# Is Creating Ad Hoc Provisioning Profiles free?

Tags: ios, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

How could you create Ad Hoc provisioning profiles for free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have an iOS developer membership first, which costs $99. But if you have that, then yes, creating an ad-hoc provisioning profile is free. You would do this thru the iOS Developer Portal, in the "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles" section on the right. It's fairly easy to figure out what to do once you're looking at the site. So if you're a registered developer, yes, you can do this for free.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you are a registered Apple Developer.